# C# WPF, dynamic tooltip, MouseLeftButtonUp not fire

Tags: c#, wpf, tooltip, mouseevent

There is code

```
ToolTip tt;

private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    Label l = new Label();
    l.Content = "ToolTip";
    l.MouseLeftButtonUp += l_MouseLeftButtonUp;
    Grid.SetColumn(l, 0);
    Grid.SetRow(l, 0);
    grid.Children.Add(l);

    tt = new ToolTip();
    tt.StaysOpen = true;
    tt.MouseLeftButtonUp += tt_MouseLeftButtonUp;
    tt.Content = "12345";

}

void l_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

    tt.IsOpen = true;

}

void tt_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

    throw new NotImplementedException();

}
```

When mouse clicked on the label tooltip is shown. Then if tooltip mouse clicked tt_MouseLeftButtonUp event is never fire. Why?

Comment: Not sure if it will work, but you could try setting the tooltip's IsHitTestVisible property to true. Alternatively, you could perhaps try a Popup element instead of ToolTip (it seems you want to open the tooltip only manually instead of having the normal/traditional automatic tooltip behavior, which would make using Popup probably the better choice).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. With popup its work fine

```
System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup popup;
```

...

```
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
sp.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10);

Label l1 = new Label();
l1.Content = "Test label 1";
l1.Tag = 1;
l1.MouseLeftButtonUp += l1_MouseLeftButtonUp;

sp.Children.Add(l1);

Border b = new Border();
b.BorderBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
b.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
b.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
b.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(10);
b.Child = sp;

popup = new System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup();
popup.Child = b;
popup.AllowsTransparency = true;
popup.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Mouse;
popup.MouseLeave += popup_MouseLeave;
```

...

```
void popup_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
popup.IsOpen = false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The ToolTips window can't accept focus,  use the Popup control instead you could use Click On it

you create  tooltips that remains open until the user clicks somewhere else. However, the ToolTipService.ShowDuration property Gives the time before tooltips  disappear automatically (default is 5 sec)  or when the user moves the mouse away. If you want to create a tooltip-like window that stays open indefinitely, the easiest approach is to use the Popup control.

Comment: I am just nitpicking here, but (input) focus and mouse actions/events are two unrelated concepts. A mouse as a pointing/positional device (and its associated events) doesn't require focus since it "pointing" at or hovering over the element establishes the association between a mouse action and this element. Input focus is for things like keyboard input, where a key press cannot by itself establish an association with the intended receiving control. This necessary association is realized by using the (input) focus mechanism.